# How to check if the user input is in a specific format?

Tags: python-2.7

i am very new to coding, and am in need of some assistance, and would like to say sorry for such a novice question, but I could not word the question in a way to easily find help, which i am sure is out there. Anyways, to put it simply, I need to force the user when asked to input text, to have the format 'a=b'.

```
`message3 = raw_input("Enter a guess in the form a=b:")`
```

I would like to make it so that if the user does not enter the correct format, 'a=b', some error message will pop up telling them so.

Comment: Use regexes to parse and get `a` and `b`, then process any exceptions.

Comment: I am sorry to be so clueless, but I honestly do not know how to do what you just said, an example or anything of the sort would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it, expanding on my comment above. Since you're learning python, it's best if you learn python 3.

```
import sys
import re

s = input("Enter a guess in the form a=b:")
matched = re.match(r'(.+)=(.+)', s)
if matched is None:
   print('enter in the form of a=b')
   sys.exit(1)
a, b = matched.groups()
print(a, b)
```

In the regex, `.+` matches a non-empty string. The brackets are a capturing group, so we can get `a` and `b` using `.groups()`.

Comment: This answer would get my +1 if you would explain what the regular expression is doing, as I am sure this is the meat of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = raw_input("Enter a guess in the form a=b:")
Enter a guess in the form a=b: Delirious=    # Incorrect Format
>>> m = re.match(r'.+=.+', string)
>>> try:
        if m.group():
            print "Correct Format"
    except:
        print "The format isn't correct"
"The format isn't correct"
>>>
>>> string = raw_input("Enter a guess in the form a=b:")
Enter a guess in the form a=b: Me=Delirious    # Correct Format
>>> m = re.match(r'.+=.+', string)
>>> try:
        if m.group():
            print "Correct Format"
    except:
        print "The format isn't correct"
"Correct Format"
```